# Change where argument to userId rather than Id

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, prisma

I am a little new to Prisma and want to see if I can change the where argument to find a cart by userId rather than the Id of the cart

I see that I can find a cart by userId if I query by carts and put in a userId in the where field but I would like to just find a cart by userId rather than the id of the cart

My datamodel.primsa

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
}

type Cart {
  id: ID! @id
  userId: User! @relation(link: INLINE)
  items: [Product!]! @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Product {
  id: ID! @id
  productName: String!
  productDescription: String!
  price: Int!
  images: [Image!]! @relation(link: INLINE)
  sku: String!
  category: Category! @relation(link: INLINE)
  inCart: [User]! @relation(link: INLINE)
}
```

My schema.graphql

```
type Query {
  products: [Product!]!
  categories: [Category!]!
  userInfo(id: String!): User!
  productsOfCategory(productName: String!): [Product!]!
  cart(userId: String!): Cart
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

type Cart {
  id: ID!
  userId: User!
  items: [Product!]!
}

type Product {
  id: ID!
  productName: String!
  productDescription: String!
  price: Int!
  images: [Image!]!
  sku: String!
  category: Category!
  inCart: [User]!
}
```

I don't want to query carts by a userID but rather a cart by userId

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

You have to use ID @id

so the datamodel looks this

```
type Cart {
  id: ID! @id
  userId: ID! @id
  items: [Product!] @relation(link: INLINE)
}
```